# "Command 'sudo' not found, did you mean" when trying to install mongodb on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, sudo

I am trying to install mongodb on Ubuntu 22.04 per the official instructions for Ubuntu Linux at
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#std-label-install-mdb-community-ubuntu

I am told to import a key with this:

```
"curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \
   sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \ --dearmor"
```

I get the following:

```
Command ' sudo' not found, did you mean:
  command 'sudo' from deb sudo (1.9.9-1ubuntu2.4)
  command 'sudo' from deb sudo-ldap (1.9.9-1ubuntu2.4)
Try: apt install <deb name>
curl: (23) Failed writing body
```

If I try "`apt-get install sudo`" I am told sudo is already the newest version (1.9.9-1ubuntu2.4).

My `$PATH` looks like this:

```
/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I used the same command you provided, and I encountered the same issue.

Below command works for me.

**curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-archive-keyring.gpg**

Comment: Thanks. I think I ended up simply using ftp to get the file on my system.